# How to convert text field to numeric field and null non-numeric values?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, numeric, alter-table

I have a column of text data which contains a bunch of various values...many of which are numbers, but others which are not.

I want to convert this text column to a numeric column and convert any values to numbers that can be done so successfully, but NULL out any text values that cannot be converted.

Is this possible in a single alter table statement?

alter table schema_1."tbl_265" alter column field_7 type numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can do this in a single statement. Postgres will try to cast each value in the column to numeric, and raise an error if that cannot be done, which will abort the whole operation.

Instead you could:

- create a new column with `numeric` datatype
- fill it with converted values - for this, the cleaner approach would be to create an ad-hoc conversion function
- drop the old string column
- rename the new numeric column

Here is **[a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5fb2f6558d4b461af380e294f5451ec2)**

```
-- sample table
create table mytable(id int primary key, col text);
insert into mytable(id, col) values
    (1, '123.5'), 
    (2, 'abc'), 
    (3, null)
;


-- conversion function
create or replace function cast_to_numeric(v_input text)
returns numeric as $$
declare v_output numeric default null;
begin
    begin
        v_output := v_input::numeric;
        exception when others then return null;
    end;
return v_output;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

-- add a new column and fill it with converted values
alter table mytable add column newcol numeric;
update mytable set newcol = cast_to_numeric(col);

-- swap the columns
alter table mytable drop column col;
alter table mytable rename column newcol to col;

-- check the results
select * from mytable
```

```
id |   col
-: | ----:
 1 | 123.5
 2 |  null
 3 |  null
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks reasonble. I was hoping for a single function, but this will do.

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to set up a pl/pgsql function [similar to this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8835/47162) first (since exceptions from type casting cannot be handled in pure SQL), but then, yes, the conversion to numeric with nulls for invalid numeric input can be performed in a single statement.

```
testdb=# create table t as select '12.34' as c union all select 'asdf';
SELECT 2
testdb=# \pset null .
Null display is ".".
testdb=# create function is_valid_numeric(text) returns boolean language plpgsql immutable as $$
begin
  return case when $1::numeric is null then false else true end;
exception when others then
  return false;
end;$$;
CREATE FUNCTION
testdb=# alter table t alter column c type numeric using case when is_valid_numeric(c) then c::numeric else null end;
ALTER TABLE
testdb=# select * from t;
   c   
-------
 12.34
     .
(2 rows)
```

You could also try to use some kind of regexp test instead of the function, but there will always be edge cases with that; the only way to be sure you don't hit a failure is to have a pl/pgsql function that actually performs the cast and handles the potential resulting exception.